# Difference between listing vs assigning true value to a rule in linter

Tags: dart

Listing a key:

```dart
linter:
  rules:
    - omit_local_variable_types
```

vs

Assigning `true` to key:

```dart
linter:
  rules:
    omit_local_variable_types: true
```

Both seems to do the same job. Is there any difference between these two ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linter configuration file us [YAML](https://yaml.org/).

The difference between:

```yaml
 rules:
   - omit_local_variable_types
```

and

```yaml
 rules:
   omit_local_variable_types: true
```

is that the former defines `rules` as being a [*sequence*](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2797382) (aka. a list) containing the string `"omit_local_variable_types"`, and the latter defines it as being a [*mapping*](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2798057) where the key `"omit_local_variable_types"` has the value `true`.

If the linter works with both, it's likely because the linter has chosen to support both formats for convenience.